# MongoDB/Mongoose aggregation or $or not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Have some checkbox buttons in html that I would like to filter the results via the API on.click, over AJAX. There are 3 kinds of results: upVoted, noVote, downVoted. Subject to which of the checkboxes are checked, a combination of upVoted, noVote, and downVoted docs would appear to the user.

The ajax calls the URL of the API, and the data reaches the database call correctly after running through the following loop in the node.js API, which loops through the array of the strings ["upVoted", "noVote", "downVoted"] (or any combination thereof) and assigns the boolean value of true to the respective variable:

```
var upVoted = false;
var noVote = false;
var downVoted = false;
storyFiltering.forEach(storyFiltering);
function storyFiltering(element, index, array) {
    if (element == 'upVoted') {upVoted = true}
    else if (element == 'noVote') {noVote = true}
    else if (element == 'downVoted') {downVoted = true}
}
console.log('upVoted: ' + upVoted + ', noVote: ' + noVote + ', downVoted: ' + downVoted);
```

These variables then match the Booleans of the voting in each of the documents.

Here's the database structure (with voting only one Boolean is ever true at once, the rest are false):

```
to: ["user1"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 4

to: ["user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 2

to: ["user1", "user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 1

to: ["user1", "user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: false,
  noVote: true,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 5

to: ["user1"],
voting: {
  upVoted: false,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: true
},
rank: 3
```

The result of the find (or aggregate) would be a callback of data filtered to match the toggled voting booleans..and then sorting them by descending 'rank'.

Toggling for all of the upVoted and noVote documents for user1 would return:

```
to: ["user1", "user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 1

to: ["user1"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 4

to: ["user1", "user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: false,
  noVote: true,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 5
```

..whereas toggling for only the upVote documents for user1 would return:

```
to: ["user1", "user2"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 1

to: ["user1"],
voting: {
  upVoted: true,
  noVote: false,
  downVoted: false
},
rank: 4
```

..and in the same pattern, toggling for all of the upVoted + noVote + downVoted documents for User 1 would return all of the documents that include User 1, sorted by rank (1, 3, 4, 5)..while, constrastly, toggling for all of the downVoted documents for User 2 would return zero documents.

Comment: Basically yes. What are you passing in as each of those values to compare? But it really does not matter, as `$or` evaluates that at least one of those conditions was true. It is also a short circuit evaluation so as soon as one condition is met then the whole thing is true. What is the result you expect to achieve? You are still using `$and` incorrectly as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn well that explains it.. Thanks for taking a look at this.. The expectation is to retrieve all of the documents for a specific user, narrowed to only include the documents that match the voting.upVoted/noVote/downVoted that's set to true, according to the filter buttons

Comment: So all of those fields set to true then.

Comment: @NeilLunn 1 of the 3 fields is true on each doc. And the frontend buttons toggle the prescence of the documents that match the toggle.

Comment: @NeilLunn ..such that there may be some combination (e.g. true, true, false), or all (true, true, true), or none (false, false, false) based on the activeness of the buttons..

Comment: Still not really clear what you are asking. If you just want one field to be true then `$or` does this. "Front end buttons" leads me to believe you are trying to match specific criteria. You would be better off going back to your question and clearly explain what your purpose is and given a sample, what you expect as a result. We should be reading your question to understand what you want, not your comments.

Comment: @NeilLunn am updating the question.. appreciate the suggestion

Comment: @NeilLunn is that clearer?

Comment: Understand that I am trying to help you towards an answer so as I have already said. Show say about 5 sample documents (just those fields) in your question with one or more you expect to match. Then show us which ones you expect to match. That is the clearest way to explain yourself. Do that and you will get an answer.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the direction. updated accordingly.. grateful for the guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your basic problem with your approach as I see it. What you are trying to do is have interaction with a user interface that "selects" certain items that you want to appear in your query results. That is all fine, but clearly you seem to be looking for "one query to rule them all" and this is where you come unstuck.

Taking your first example, your query for all "upvote" and "novote" documents comes out like this. Also stating away from aggregate right now, but the same applies as a query to a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "to": { "$in": ["user1"] },
    "$or": [
        { "voting.upVoted": true },
        { "voting.noVote": true }
    ]
})
```

That returns your expected results as the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) considers that "either" of those conditions could evaluate to `true` in order to satisfy the match. As explained before, all queries in MongoDB are implicitly an "and" query, so there is no need for the additional operator here.

In your next example, you really only need **one** of your criteria to be true, so we could remove the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) but I'll leave it here for the explanation later.

```js
db.collection.find({
    "to": { "$in": ["user1"] },
    "$or": [
        { "voting.upVoted": true }
    ]
})
```

Again that matches your expected result as this returns both where the "user1" is present "and" that the "upVoted" value is `true`.

But now onto your interface interaction and how to handle that. Let us say that you have input coming from your interface that looks something like this:

```js
{
   "to": "user1",
   "voting": {
      "upVoted": true,
      "downVoted": false,
      "noVote": true
   }
}
```

That confirms your basic selections in your user interface that were made for the query. In order to "process" this into your desired query then consider the following JavaScript code, to translate into whatever language you want to implement in. I'm just going to assume that structure as shown to be in a variable known as `request`:

```js
var query = {
    "to": { "$in": [] },
    "$or": []
};

for ( k in request ) {
    if ( k == "to" )
        query.to["$in"].push( request.to );

    if ( k == "voting" ) {
        for ( v in request[k] ) {
            if ( request[k][v] ) {      // if that value is `true`
                var obj = {};
                obj[ k + "." + v] = true;
                query["$or"].push( obj );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code over that data the resulting `query` object now looks like:

```js
{
    "to" : {
            "$in" : [
                    "user1"
            ]
    },
    "$or" : [
            {
                    "voting.upVoted" : true
            },
            {
                    "voting.noVote" : true
            }
    ]
}
```

Which is the same as the query we issued first, and changing your selections in `request` to look the way it would in the second example:

```js
{
   "to": "user1",
   "voting": {
      "upVoted": true,
      "downVoted": false,
      "noVote": false
   }
}
```

The the resulting `query` object is:

```js
{
    "to" : {
            "$in" : [
                    "user1"
            ]
    },
    "$or" : [
            {
                    "voting.upVoted" : true
            }
    ]
}
```

All that is left to do is issue the query which uses the object as it's argument:

```js
db.collection.find( query )
```

So that is how you interact with data from your interface. You build dynamically, rather than try to throw all of the values you got in the `response` as parameters in the query.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the walkthrough on dynamically building db calls..much more expansive. Will revise the response and update accordingly..first thing in the morning.. many thanks again